# Powershell - Can it be determined if a script is run by right click "run with powershell"?

Tags: powershell, command-line

Background:
I wrote a little script for our 1st level tech support that does some validation (naming convention/ip address range) and updates dns records for the printer ranges.

It takes input from the command line Or a file, and if no input is given on the command line it prompts from within the script.

The original issue was that the script just executed and closed when a user right clicked the update-PrinterDNS.ps1 and "run with PowerShell".  Adding a pause statement at the end of the script allows the user to see the output. However this throws a wrench into the automation side when the script is called and passed parameters.

I've considered adding a -noPause switch to the command line, or pushing out a shortcut that calls PowerShell with -noExit, but those seem more like workarounds instead of solutions.

the Question:)
I'd like to know if it can be determined within the script if it was started by the 'run with windows PowerShell' in order to conditionally pause at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run with PowerShell has the following command line (by default, subject to change in future versions, etc.):

```
powershell.exe "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
```

You can see how you were called in the `$MyInvocation` variable.

Another way is to check the execution policy, which is explicitly set here. Unless you started PowerShell with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` the following will only be true for the case when your script was run via the context menu:

```
(Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process) -eq 'Bypass'
```

As far as hacky workarounds go, I'd say this *should* work for a while. No guarantees, though.

Comment: Thanks, both of these work for my needs.  I've gone with the $MyInvocation match route for this environment.

Answer (score 3):

The invocation line is populated with the command used to launch the script. I would expect it to always have a value if invoked from a PowerShell prompt, but it is empty when doing a Run with PowerShell.

`echo "hello world"
if ($MyInvocation.Line -eq "")
{
    pause
}`

Comment: in testing this, I found it to be the opposite. Changing it to be -ne works.

Comment: This should only pause when doing a Run with PowerShell.

Comment: In 2022, on comparing a console run to a right-click "Run with PowerShell" run with PowerShell 5.1, the following works for me: `if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq "&") { pause }` to cause only the "Run with PowerShell" to pause at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using $MyInvocation should be fine in the main body of the script.
It will not work however when used to test from a function.

Example:

```
function ConditionalPause()
{
    if ($MyInvocation.Line -ne "")
    {
        pause  #will ALWAYS pause
    }

    # $MyInvocation.Line will be always the name of the function, i.e.: "ConditionalPause"
    # $MyInvocation.Line -ne "" will always return true
}
```